# Using regex in Notepad++, how to capture previous line after matching an expression

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have a file with thousands of entries like:

```
<Source foo="goo">
    <Name label="SomeLabel"/>
</Source>
<Target foo="bar">
    <Name label="SomeLabel"/>
</Target>
```

The only thing that changes is the "SomeLabel" string.  I'm trying to write a search expression in Notepad++ that will return either just the 'SomeLabel' strings, or at least the entire  line.  However, I *only* want that line if it is between the <Target> tags; I don't want the <Source> nodes.  I know I need to use a lookbehind (or lookahead), but I just can't figure it out, especially with the <> characters in the string to match.

Thanks!

Comment: May you can not do that with `notepad++`  but I can give you the easy way with **Perl** if can use it

Comment: @k-five: Of course, you can do that in `notepad++`.

Answer (score 0):

The <> aren't really a problem. Under these limitations, you can easily grab just the tag you want with

```
[^"]+(?="\/>[^<]*<\/Target)
```

Comment: That will return the Name nodes between the Source tags, though.  I only want the Name nodes that are between Target tags.  Thanks.

Comment: @elora Sorry, fixed with positive look-ahead for Target

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following expression

```
<Target[^>]*>             # match <Target...>
(?:(?!</Target>)[\s\S])*? # match anything afterwards, 
                          # make sure not to overrun </Target>
label="SomeLabel"         # match label="SomeLabel"
(?:(?!</Target>)[\s\S])*? # same as above
</Target>                 # closing Tag
```

Here, only the entries with `label="SomeLabel"` are selected, use the **verbose mode** and see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/4WLYGu/1).

Comment: Thanks.  I can get this mostly working on regex101.com (it still returns the <Target> and not just the label), but I haven't managed to get it to work in Notepad++ yet.  I'll keep fiddling.